# Docker volume mounting issue on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm running **Docker for Mac** on my Macbook with following details:-

OS version - **MacOS Big Sur version 11.6**,
Docker for Mac version - **4.1.0**,
Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing - **unchecked**

I'm trying to mount sub-folder '.aws' which is present inside the /Users folder however getting the mounts denied error.

I have explicitly added that sub-directory inside the Docker's settings.json file however the problem still persists.

Docker settings.json file:-

```
"filesharingDirectories": [
    "/Users",
    "/Volumes",
    "/private",
    "/tmp",
    "/var/folders",
    "/Users/.aws"
  ],
```

This is how Im trying to run the container inside the /Users director:-

```
docker run -v ${pwd}/.aws:/.aws:ro test-image arn:aws:iam::924295503423:role/jenkins
```

**Error:-**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:
The path /.aws
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Any thoughts?
I would really appreciate your advise on this, thanks

Comment: It looks like `${pwd}` is expanding to an empty string.  Do you mean the shell variable `$PWD` perhaps, or to spell out the absolute path to the current directory?

Comment: thanks $PWD was the culprit here